# Laravel how to store more foreign data together with the foreign key (on creation)

Tags: laravel, laravel-migrations

I have a many to many relation ship between my Job and Company models.

Here is a small part of the migration that handles the relation:

```
$table->bigInteger('company_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies')->onDelete('cascade');
$table->string('company_name')->references('name')->on('companies')->onDelete('cascade');
```

The first two lines create the foreign key. After writing some more code I came to the conclusion that I use a companies name a lot when I need to use the Job model, so now I want to store company_name in the Job model together with the foreign key. The foreign key is set on creation, can I do this with the company_name as well?
The third line did not do the trick:

```
$table->string('company_name')->references('name')->on('companies')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Laravel says: General error: 1364 Field 'company_name' doesn't have a default value.

Comment: i think it's becuz you already have some data in table  , just add nullable to your foreign key so those old data can have null value

Comment: @hretic This application is not in use yet, so I just ran my migrations  fresh again, no data is in the database.

Comment: If the application is not in use (i.e. it's new code) your migration should look much different than that. Check modern migration code which should look like `$table->foreignId('company_id')->cascadeOnDelete()->constrained();` instead of what you have there, which looks very dated. https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Comment: As for your question: don't do that, it's not how relational databases are supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Add unique index on name in companies tabele. To work as expected, `companies` table must contain unique name values

```
$table->unique('name');
```

```
$table->string('company_name');

$table->foreign('company_name')
    ->references('name')
    ->on('companies')
    ->onDelete('cascade');
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It is not possible to do this without making name an action foreign key? (This does not have any downsides for my application, but I am just curious).